# Exception on try to compare only date from datetime with ef core 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-core-3.0, ef-core-3.0

After update ef core to 3.0, when a try to truncate time and compare only date from a datetime, the ef core return a error:

```
The LINQ expression 'Where<Category>(\n    source: DbSet<Category>, \n    predicate: (c) => c.CreateAt.Date == DateTime.Now.Date)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

For this query:

```
Context.Category.Where(c => c.CreateAt.Date == DateTime.Now.Date).AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
```

I need compare only date ignoring the time from a DateTimeOffSet property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `DateTime.Now` is the issue here.

I don't know the data, and I don't know if you store the time component, but there are two options you could try.

If you want to compare two timestamps, take the `.Now` out of the lamba and try the following.

```
var today = DateTime.Now.Date; // Or DateTime.Today
Context.Category.Where(c => c.CreateAt.Date == today ).AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
```

If you want all records for today you can try the following.

```
var start = DateTime.Today;
var end = Date.Time.Today.AddDays(1); // the following midnight

var todaysCats = Context.Category.Where(c => c.CreateAt >= start && c.CreateAt < end ) // note '>=' and '<'
```

---

BTW. It' better to use Utc timestamps for `CreatedAt`-like fields. It pays off in the long term.

Comment: But i need compare date without time